# Загрузка процессора почти 100 процентов на VPS

Tags: vps

Информация по VPS

```
Процессор   10 X Intel Core Processor (Skylake) 2200.002 MHz
Оперативная память  8522 / 11984 MiB
Размер дискового пространства   0.99 TiB
Файл подкачки (swap)    1292 MiB
Средняя загрузка (1, 5, 15 мин) 101.26 53.76 41.72
Продолжительность работы    3 days 1 hours 20 minutes
Количество процессов    493
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Список процессов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Комманда `mysqladmin -u root -p status`

```
Uptime: 3439  Threads: 65  Questions: 2303950  Slow queries: 6111  Opens: 586  Flush tables: 1  Open table
s: 400  Queries per second avg: 669.947
```

Перевод:

```
Время, проведённое на сайте: 3439 Темы: 65 Вопросы: 2303950 Медленные запросы: 6111 Открывает: 586 Таблицы флеша: 1 Открыть стол
s: 400 Количество запросов в секунду: 669.947
```

`Количество запросов в секунду: 669.947` это 669 тысяч запросов в секунду к бд?

Куда копать?

Comment: 669 целых, 947 тысячных запроса в секунду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится
Прошелся по логу сайтов, в `access.log` нашел, что каждую секунду, а то и чаще на сайт заходит некий SemrushBot

```
46.229.168.130 - - [04/Dec/2018:10:20:20 +0300] "GET /ugolok-alyuminievyj-40 HTTP/1.1" 200 296 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
46.229.168.137 - - [04/Dec/2018:10:20:21 +0300] "GET /shina-alyuminievaya-12x150 HTTP/1.0" 200 535 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
46.229.168.137 - - [04/Dec/2018:10:20:21 +0300] "GET /shina-alyuminievaya HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
46.229.168.132 - - [04/Dec/2018:10:20:22 +0300] "GET /setka-riflenaya-dlya?add-to-cart=41855 HTTP/1.0" 200 534 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
46.229.168.132 - - [04/Dec/2018:10:20:22 +0300] "GET /setka-riflena?add-to-cart=41855 HTTP/1.1" 200 297 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
```

Поставил ограничения на просмотр боту

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SemrushBot                                                                 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]                                                                                   

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SemrushBot/2~bl                                                            
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]                                                                                   

Order allow,deny                                                                                          
allow from all                                                                                            
Deny from 46.229.168.
```

По название + по ip

`robots.txt`

```
User-agent: SemrushBot                                                                                    
Disallow: /                                                                                               
User-agent: SemrushBot/2~bl                                                                               
Disallow: /
```

Нагрузка упала меньше 10, но бот все равно заходит на сайт, но уже видит ошибку 403